# Do I need RAID if I have one disk?

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, dualboot, ubuntu-20.04

Some days ago I've got an idea to install Ubuntu 20.04 Linux together with Windows 10. But I found out that I have RST technology on my laptop, and it's on, so the installation stopped before beginning. I read some topics. They said it is dangerous for Windows.

So should I change RAID to AHCI or it would be better not trying to install it more?

Comment: You can’t do RAID with one disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intel RST supports one disk, but it wont let you create a RAID with it (obviously :)

When you enable Intel RAID, you need (or Windows will automatically) install drivers for RST and all the data will be treated through the Intel RST driver. Intel RAID is handled by the main CPU anyway so no harm there.

It depends on the bios and motherboard, but when you use the Intel RST you can use the Intel Rapid Storage console and see some more information about your HDD and probably set some more settings.

[Intel RST Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1e2Q.png)

Comment: So actually I can turn RST off. But can it damage Windows?

Comment: If you are just going to install windows and you will not need RAID then it doesn't matter if you have the RST on or off and you can use just AHCI. AHCI would be probably better for Linux.
If you have SSD, I would suggest to turn it on. AHCI should have TRIM support, but the drivers for RST in windows are much better and should provide better performance and control over all drives.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you plan on installing another disk, which is unlikely in most laptop setups, there is no need to set the disks to RAID.  I would set it to AHCI, to prevent possible confusion or issues down the line.  If I remember correctly, setting it to RAID with a single disk, defaults to AHCI, but that might depend on the BIOS.  Better to set it manually, to be safe.

On a side note, some RAID controllers allow RAID with one disk.  Typically this allows you set up the RAID volume in preparation for adding more disks down the line.  Obviously, a RAID of one disk offers no redundancy or speed improvements.  I dont know if Intel RST supports single disk RAIDs.